# How to verify the structure -- and not values -- in a PACT consumer test?

Tags: java, testing, pact, pact-broker

I have the following consumer test (excerpt of):

```java
new PactDslJsonArray()
    .object()
        .stringType("createdBy")
        .booleanType("isLastVersion")
        .integerType("orderNumber")
    .closeObject()
    .object()
       .stringType("createdBy")
       .booleanType("isLastVersion")
       .integerType("orderNumber")
    .closeObject()
    .object()
       .stringType("createdBy")
       .booleanType("isLastVersion")
       .integerType("orderNumber")
    .closeObject();
```

that generates this interaction:

```java
{
  "consumer": {
    "name": "bm"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "Get budgets for specific project",
      "providerStates": [
        {
          "name": "PMM module is running"
        }
      ],
      "request": {
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/budgets/project/002e3ac0-1b4e-4450-a44e-a90532acfa33"
      },
      "response": {
        "body": [
          {
            "createdBy": "string",
            "isLastVersion": true,
            "orderNumber": 100
          },
          {
            "createdBy": "string",
            "isLastVersion": true,
            "orderNumber": 100
          },
          {
            "createdBy": "string",
            "isLastVersion": true,
            "orderNumber": 100
          }
        ],
        "generators": {
          "body": {
            "$[0].createdBy": {
              "size": 20,
              "type": "RandomString"
            },
            "$[0].orderNumber": {
              "max": 2147483647,
              "min": 0,
              "type": "RandomInt"
            },
            "$[1].createdBy": {
              "size": 20,
              "type": "RandomString"
            },
            "$[1].orderNumber": {
              "max": 2147483647,
              "min": 0,
              "type": "RandomInt"
            },
            "$[2].createdBy": {
              "size": 20,
              "type": "RandomString"
            },
            "$[2].orderNumber": {
              "max": 2147483647,
              "min": 0,
              "type": "RandomInt"
            }
          }
        },
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "matchingRules": {
          "body": {
            "$[0].createdBy": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$[0].isLastVersion": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$[0].orderNumber": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "integer"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$[1].createdBy": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$[1].isLastVersion": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$[1].orderNumber": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "integer"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$[2].createdBy": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$[2].isLastVersion": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "type"
                }
              ]
            },
            "$[2].orderNumber": {
              "combine": "AND",
              "matchers": [
                {
                  "match": "integer"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "status": 200
      }
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pact-jvm": {
      "version": "4.6.7"
    },
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "3.0.0"
    }
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "pmm"
  }
}
```

When I verify this with the broker, though, I get the following errors:

```
"differences": [
          {
            "description": "Expected a String (like \"string\") but got nil at $[0].createdBy"
          },
          {
            "description": "Expected 100 but got 1 at $[0].orderNumber"
          },
          {
            "description": "Expected a String (like \"string\") but got nil at $[1].createdBy"
          },
          {
            "description": "Expected 100 but got 2 at $[1].orderNumber"
          },
          {
            "description": "Expected a String (like \"string\") but got nil at $[2].createdBy"
          },
          {
            "description": "Expected 100 but got 3 at $[2].orderNumber"
          }
        ]
```

which lead me to believe the consumer test generates interactions that bind actual values rather than the structure -- which is what I would like to verify.

Am I doing anything wrong here? In that case, how do I verify the structure of objects rather than the values for their fields?

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Your consumer contract using `xxxType` is the way to go. The result you get when verifying is strange. Can you share more code? How are you building the Pact files? How are you verifying? Any chance you verify against a previous version of the contract?